# How can the range be adjusted on a JavaFX stacked area chart?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX stacked area chart, and I'd like to fix the range that it automatically adjusts when data is added. Currently, the Y axis (which is just a `NumberAxis`) goes up to a number that is way too high:

[image: stacked area chart]

I tried lowering the upper limit of the Y axis by doing:

```
((NumberAxis)chart.getYAxis()).setUpperBound(2000);
```

where `chart` is a `StackedAreaChart`. This doesn't seem to have any effect, unfortunately. How can I set the upper limit of the Y axis in a JavaFX chart?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you set the autoranging property of the axis to false (NumberAxis#setAutoRanging)?

Comment: @sarcan Wow, you're right. No I didn't.

Comment: @sarcan If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chart axes in JavaFX will require you to set the 'autoRanging' property to false before applying a custom range.

Arguably, it would be nice if the chart node raised an error when you attempt to set the value for an axis with autoranging == true, but at least for JavaFX 2.2 that is not the case.